# DrawerNavigator inside the header of a StackNavigator

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a DrawerNavigator

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home},
  Profile: { screen: Profile}
});
```

I have a DrawerButton that looks like this

```
const DrawerButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}}>
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/buttons/menu.png')}
          style={{ width: 200, height: 80, resizeMode: 'contain' }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I have a StackNavigator, where I change the navigationsOptions at every screen.

```
const AppRouteConfigs = createStackNavigator({
  Drawer: {
    screen: Drawer,    
  },
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
      headerTransparent: true
    })
  },
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.blue
      },
      headerTitle: <NavBarComponent />,
      headerRight:  <DrawerButton navigation={navigation} />,
      headerLeft: (
        <View style={{ padding: 15, paddingLeft: 10 }}>
          <Icon
            name="chevron-left"
            size={25}
            style={{ color: colors.white }}
            onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
          />
        </View>
      )
    })
  });
```

I would like that when I click on the right of the header, the Drawer menu opens. This doesn't work. Nothing happens at all for now when I click on it. I'm using `React-Navigation 3.0.9`. The `navigation.goBack()` functions, and the button is correctly clicked (if I assign `props.navigation.navigate('Home')` to the `onPress()` function of the button, it navigates there as expected). I'm testing with an Android device.

How could I make it work ?

Comment: Try nesting `StackNavigator` inside `DrawerNavigator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open or close drawer in a scene/screen which isn't defined inside the Drawer-Navigator.

Drawer can be toggled from any scene which is defined in it. So you should define Home inside it rather then in StackNavigator like this -

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Profile: { screen: Profile}
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.blue
      },
      headerTitle: <NavBarComponent />,
      headerRight:  <DrawerButton navigation={navigation} />,
      headerLeft: (
        <View style={{ padding: 15, paddingLeft: 10 }}>
          <Icon
            name="chevron-left"
            size={25}
            style={{ color: colors.white }}
            onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
          />
        </View>
      )
    })
  }
});

const AppRouteConfigs = createStackNavigator({
  Drawer: {
    screen: Drawer,    
  },
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
      headerTransparent: true
    })
  },
});
```

Also you can use `toggleDrawer` function provided by `react-navigation` to toggle the drawer

```
const DrawerButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.navigation.toggleDrawer}>
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/buttons/menu.png')}
          style={{ width: 200, height: 80, resizeMode: 'contain' }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't work. It only creates a white header on top with a broken back button. The image menu doesn't even appear. The Stack Navigator is my "main" navigator, and it is sent to a reduxifyNavigator function from Redux. If I nest the DrawerNavigator inside the Stack one instead and return that one, it doesn't show anything at all...

Comment: Nevermind, got it working by putting the navigationsOptions outside of the screens.